# number of month with 31 day within two dates with sumproduct

Tags: excel-formula

I have two dates and i neeed get number of month with 31 day. Example: First date 03.02.2016 Last date 17.12.2016 (Number of month with 31 day is 6. How i get this number of month with =SUMPRODUCT function?

Answer (score 1):

If the two dates are within the same year then,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(DATE(YEAR(A1), ROW(INDIRECT(MONTH(A1)+1&":"&MONTH(B1))), 0))=31))
```

This yields 5, not 6 which appears correct unless you want Dec-2016 included.

This may be better a formula and should span more than a single year.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(ROW(INDIRECT(INT(A1)&":"&INT(B1))))=31))
```

If you need to include Dec-2016 then change B1 to eomonth(b1, 0).

Comment: OK, that int confused me at first.  Is the INT even needed? or is that just to keep it clean in case there is some portion of time embedded with the date?

Comment: I added the int 'cause I wasn't sure if row would take dates as start and stop markers.

Comment: both the last formula and the modified last formula: =SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(ROW(INDIRECT(INT(A1)&":"&INT(EOMONTH(B1,0)))))=31)) worked for me.  unmodified resulted in 5 and modified 6.  One caveat Jeeped did not mention is that your dates need to be actual dates in excel and not text.  This can be tested by using something like ISTEXT(A1)

Answer (score 0):

Jepped sorry , this formula don't work for months with 30 days
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(ROW(INDIRECT(INT(A1)&":"&INT(B1))))=30))